# Clone File Structure Of Pending Changes In Visual Studio

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, tfs

I'm using TFS and Git in Visual Studio and I'd like to be able to export or clone all pending files and the file structure to a folder of my choosing so that my pending changes can be backed up locally instead of shelving or stashing the pending files. I'm currently having to open each file in windows explorer and then run a script to copy the file along with its file structure to my backup location, which is time consuming and prone to manual error. Does anyone know of a plug-in, feature in TFS, any Git tool or something in Visual Studio that will copy pending files and their file structure to a folder of my choosing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use TFS API to achieve what you want. Get all files 、folders and get their directories. Judge if the file is pending change. Then use your script to copy the file to your backup location .

A code of workspace  for you reference:

```
private void PopulateTreeView(string workspaceName)
{
    // Connect to TFS - VersionControlServer Service
    var tfs =
        TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection
        (new Uri("https://tfs2010:8080/defaultcollection"));
    var vcs = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    // Get the workspace the user has currently selected
    var workspace = vcs.QueryWorkspaces(workspaceName, 
        vcs.AuthorizedUser, Environment.MachineName)[0];
    _workspace = workspace;
    tvWksNavigator.Nodes.Clear();

    // Loop through all folders and get directories and files
    foreach (var folder in workspace.Folders)
    {
        var info = new DirectoryInfo(folder.LocalItem);
        if (info.Exists)
        {
            var rootNode = new TreeNode(info.Name) { Tag = info };
            GetDirectories(info.GetDirectories(), rootNode);
            tvWksNavigator.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the method QueryPendingChanges, it is possible to pass a file path and see if the file is pending change, if so, what is lock type, and also get the download details for the file.

```
var status = _workspace.QueryPendingSets(new[] { new ItemSpec(
                                                    dir.FullName, 
                                                    RecursionType.None) },
                                                    _workspace.Name, vcs.AuthorizedUser, 
                          false);
```